# pgrep detect duplicate processes

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to use pgrep to first detect if a process is running and if so, determine if the process has been duplicated (run) accidentally. If so, it should it kill the duplicate processes.

```
if ! pgrep -f "java" > /dev/null; then
  echo "Yes its running but there may be duplicates"
  < Now check for duplicates here and kill if necessary >
fi
```

Please help

*** UPDATE ***

ps aux:

```
debian    2521  3.8  5.4 407212 27524 pts/0    Sl   20:16   0:08 java -cp somefile.jar
```

Code:

```
if [ $(pgrep -f "somefile.jar" | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then
  kill $(pgrep -f "somefile.jar" | grep -v $(pgrep -o "somefile.jar") | awk '{printf $1" "}');
fi
```

Works but throws an error

*** UPDATE ***

Here is a direct paste of my code:

```
if [ $(pgrep -f java | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then
  echo "kill $(pgrep -f java | grep -v $(pgrep -of java) | sort -n | uniq | awk '{printf $1" "}')";
fi
```

Comment: How would you determine which one among the two to kill? The one whose PID is number is higher than the other one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(pgrep -f java | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then 
  kill $(pgrep -f java | grep -v $(pgrep -of java) | sort -n | uniq | awk '{printf $1" "}');
fi
```

`pgrep -o` will give you the oldest (most likely the first) java process. You want `grep -v` that process and kill others.

Comment: This works GREAT, but what if I want to identify the java process by say the jar file its running. For example, see the edit above. This would allow killing of java pertaining to an application and not affect other java apps on a shared server.

Comment: This is the error I get. I know its not much help. line 16: kill: (2836) - No such process

Comment: @Atomiklan Most likely the same process is being called by two or more jar files. It gets printed twice. You can use `uniq` to print the process id just once. See my edit.

Comment: What is the purpose of the awk (and sort, uniq, etc)? Everything else makes sense.

Comment: Ah and that error is back again. Cant find process. Weird. I didnt change anything.

Comment: @Atomiklan without `awk` in that line, it will print each process line-by-line. If you have 5 additional process it will print 5 lines. `awk printf $1" "` prints it like the following : `procid1 procid2 procid3`...

Comment: @Atomiklan : before you run kill, just echo "kill...." the whole command. You can then check which processes it is trying to kill. With `sort` and `uniq` it shouldn't happen.

Comment: If I make sure two java apps are running (example PID 0001 and 0002) the first time I run the script (echo "kill.....") it lists 0002 to be killed but its also listing a second unknown process (Something random like 4123), possibly the command itself? Immediately after running, that process is gone making me think it was that command executing and has since terminated. Its ever changing too with each run of the script.

Comment: `pgrep` should't print the `pgrep` comamnd process id. are you sure you are using `grep -v $(pgrep -of java)` ?

Comment: See the update in the main post. Pasted my code in which should have been a direct paste of your original code.

Comment: pgrep -f java | grep -v $(pgrep -of java) lists 3 of the 4 java processes running and some miscellaneous process.

Comment: Weird... Ok if I do pgrep -f java | grep -v $(pgrep -of somefile.jar) I get three processes. As soon as I try to use java, or the file name for both searches, the forth and random process appears in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the return code of pgrep, but the output might be more useful if you need to know how many.

```
HOW_MANY_JAVAS = $(pgrep -f 'java' | wc -l)
if ((HOW_MANY_JAVAS > 1)) ; then
  echo 'too much Java.'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
# Collect pids of all java processes in sorted order.
readarray -t PIDS < <(exec pgrep -f java | sort -n)

# Kill all pids except the first.
[[ ${#PIDS[@]} -gt 1 ]] && kill "${PIDS[@]:2}"
```